# How to plot ROC curve for multiclass Xgboost using python?

Tags: python, xgboost, roc

In my model, the classes are [0,1,2,3].
As ROC is used in binary classification or OneVsRest multiclass problems, I want to plot ROC curve for classes[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]. What should I do?

Comment: can you add some data ?

Answer (score 0):

ROC curves are modelled for binary problems. OneVsAll is one method to do so where your main class in considered as positive label and others as negative.According to your problem you want to model the problem as OneVsOne which is good. Since this is another method for making binary classifers work for your multiclass classification.
Caution : OneVsOne method is computationally expensive.
See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html) for further reading.

For classes [0,1,2] it would return [0,1], [0,2],[1,2] i.e for 3 classes it would return 3(3-1)/2 i.e 3 classifiers. Now you have 3 binary classifier. I hope it is easy for you to follow from here on how to get your ROC curves from this point.